# Как определить <div> … </div> пустой или с дополнительными элементами?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Используется: WebDriver, С#

**ИМЕЕТСЯ**
Имеется страница с  div … /div.
Содержание div … /div после каждого обновления страницы не прогнозировано меняется.

Т.е.
    Вар 1  div пустой /div
    Вар 2  div … набор элементов … /div

**ВОПРОС**
 Как реализовать сценарий: если div пустой /div, то обновить страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Обновить страницу можно используя `driver.Navigate().Refresh();`, проверить значение `.Text` у нужного элемента я думаю проблем не составит

```
var div = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("div"));

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(div.Text))
{
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
}
```

Comment: На странице много div. Как сделать чтобы предложенное вами решение работало с нужным div?

Comment: @koverflow что в вашем понимании нужный div? как вы определяете что из десятка div вам нужен именно один? по какому признаку?

Comment: @ tCode Кажется понял. Я его по id определю

Comment: @koverflow тогда так: `var div = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("div")).First(e => e.GetAttribute("id") == "некоторый id");`